# eclipse error: Selection must be WSDL

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl, jax-ws

I am trying to create a simple web service using Apache CXF 2.6 runtime in Tomcat v7 using Java in Eclipse. I am following this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2Vjs8ylmFM&feature=autoplay&list=ULtSVs_nwD1Ug&playnext=1

In this video i am following the wizard create a new XML based Web Service in Eclipse.

In the wizard Web Service type is Bottom up Java Bean Web Service. There are two sliders and i want it to indicate Test Service and Test Client to recreate the error i.e Selection must be WSDL which appears at the end of Test Client.

Please help me understand what am i missing ?

Comment: I found this link but couldn't understand much http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.0/news/jst-ws-1.0news.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm I got the same message with CXF 2.7.2

I went back and added annotations within the create a Service Endpoint Interface section of the wizard (I created and SEI) and it worked.

I think, because neither my implementation nor the service endpoint interface had annotations originally, the WSDL could not be generated and the wizard could not continue, generating a 'Selection must be WSDL' message instead...or at least that is my belief at the moment :)

Comment: which annotations did you add?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with CXF version 2.6.1. But I tried with CXF version 2.3.11. Now it works :) but not clear why it doesn't work with version 2.6.1.

Comment: None of the mirror to download this version work anymore, so probably one of the answer below is a better solution

Comment: @Omkar : I have the same problem and i am not able to create a web service, referring to [this](http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/apachecxf/2.3.11) link, the version 2.3.11 is not available, how can i get it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same Error with CXF 2.7.1. This Error happened When I got 2 Services in WSDL and try to create Web Service Client out of it. I don't know why its showing up weird error because I am generating Client stubs from WSDL only. But when I create with One Service in WSDL, I didn't get any error. Do you know how to handle WSDL when its got 2 Services inside? How to generate Client out of that WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error and got the thing work by rigth-clicking the java class and selecting new->web service, instead of selecting the java resources package

Comment: didn't help in my case, I have apache cxf 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

> In the wizard Web Service type is Bottom up Java Bean Web Service. There are two sliders and i want it to indicate Test Service and Test Client to recreate the error i.e Selection must be WSDL which appears at the end of Test Client.

Beneath the "Bottom up Java Bean Web Service" you specified a class.
Inspect this class' methods. 
The methods cannot have an unknown (to the web service client's) return values.

Answer (score 0):

I was the same error But I solved it.
My case is ... Because class not created. First check your compile class,  Build path > output folder.
if class not found then Build Path > Order and Export :  all check after  Project Clean and
check compile class.
Sorry I'm poor English But Let you know my experience.
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Actually just changing the CXF version helped me. I Recommend to do the same
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

None of the answer work for me as well. So I observed that launching the server and client together showed this error for the client. When I tried starting the only server keeping client off I am able to do that without any issues. Only thing is that I don't get UI to test the service, but I can test it using soap UI.

Answer (score -1):

I am newbie in Java WebService and was also facing the similar issue while following a [tutorial](https://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/jaxwscxf_step1/)

I downgraded the CXF version from 3.1.1 to 2.4.2, cleaned-out the old dependencies and rebuilt the project. And it started working for me.

P.S. - I am using JDK 1.7.